# How to debug PostgreSQL Error in MVC Website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, nancy

When performing an update command on my PostgreSQL database I am getting a very obscure error.

How can I further debug this error to understand what is going wrong. I cant come up with a way to further debug this? From my inspection I cannot determine the cause; the table exists, the input values are valid. And the output error (first line) is extremely unhelpful...

```
System.NotSupportedException: Backend sent unrecognized response type: e
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses_Ver_3>d__a.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject()
   at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRowDescription()
   at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 dataEnumeration, Command
Behavior behavior, NpgsqlCommand command, NotificationThreadBlock threadBlock, Boolean synchOnReadError)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(CommandBehavior cb)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<ExecuteImplAsync>d__152.MoveNext() in D:\Dev\dapper-dot-
net\Dapper NET45\SqlMapperAsync.cs:line 275
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Server.Data.TeamCommands.AddMemberToTeamCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNex
t() in .......\TeamCommands\AddMemberToTeamCommand.cs:line 33
```

Function causing the error:

```
public async Task<int> ExecuteAsync(IDbConnection conn, IDbTransaction transition, long userId)
{
    const string sql = "INSERT INTO members_teams (member_id, team_id) VALUES (:memberId, :teamId);";

    // Line 33: error occurs here
    var result = await conn.ExecuteAsync(
         sql,
         new { memberId = MemberTeam.MemberId, teamId = MemberTeam.TeamId },
         transition);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Anything in the *Postgres* server log from around the time of the error that looks like it may be related?

Comment: Looks like a protocol handling issue in nPgSQL. It's getting an unexpected message on the wire protocol that it isn't expecting. 'e' doesn't appear in the main wire protocol as a message type, but it looks like it's parsing row description metadata at the time of the error. If updating to the latest nPgSQL doesn't help you should report a bug to nPgSQL. If possible attach a network capture from wireshark, or a self-contained reproducible test case.